# How can I assign a value to a global variable ondrag event form an element?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<head>

<style>
.droptarget {
    float: left; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 35px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

> 3 draggable objects that each perform a specific function when
>   dragged need to change the global variable value "elDragged" each time on these paragraphs are dragged to the box.

```
<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)"
  draggable="true" id="dragtarget1" eldraged.value = 1>Drag me #1!</p>

</div>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)"
  draggable="true" id="dragtarget2" eldraged.value = 2 >Drag me  #2!</p>

</div>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)"
  draggable="true" id="dragtarget3" eldraged.value = 3>Drag me #3!</p>
</div>



<!-- Empty Drag Box-->
<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

> I've set up the code below to test if the global changes which it does not

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var eldraged ="";

function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragging(event) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eldraged + " " + "Dragging";
}

function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eldraged + " " + "Dropped";
    function processChoice()
}
```

> When the drop event occurs it supposed to assigns the global variable for whatever number the value is for the specific drag and drop event. then what ever number the global variable is defines the call of the function for it below. I can't seem to pass that global anything no matter what I drop and how I try it. basically each drop is suppossed to have its own function to draw on a canvas in my main program

```
//functions for each separate draged item
function processChoice(){
switch (elDraged ) {
    case 1:
        //Does Work for drag1
        Function1();
        break;
    case 2:
    //Does Work for drag2
        Function2();;
        break;
    case 3:
    //Does Work for drag3
        Function3();;
        break;
}
</script>

</body>
```